# What is the use of AtomicReferenceArray?

Tags: java, concurrency

When is it a good idea to use `AtomicReferenceArray`? Please explain with an example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

looks like it's functionally equivalent to `AtomicReference[]`, occupying a little less memory though.

So it's useful when you need more than a million atomic references - can't think of any use case.

Comment: Much better answer than the accepted one. It saves space vs an AtomicReference[] - one copy of the Unsafe class, lots of object references it can act upon.

Answer (score 11):

If you had a shared array of object references, then you would use an `AtomicReferenceArray` to ensure that the array couldn't be updated simultaneously by different threads i.e. only one element can be updated at a time.

However, in an `AtomicReference[]` (array of `AtomicReference`) multiple threads can still update different elements simulateously, because the atomicity is on the elements, not on the array as a whole.

More info [here](http://www.java-forums.org/threads-synchronization/25324-atomicreferencearray-t-equivalent-array-atomicreference-t.html).

Comment: multiple threads can update AtomicReferenceArray elements simultaneously.

Comment: They can't. Read the link I posted.

Comment: Then what is the difference between `AtomicReferenceArray` and `AtomicReference[]`? Sun's implementation is by Doug Lea.

Comment: It uses less space, because each atomic reference in the `AtomicReferenceArray` only takes up one pointer. The `compareAndSet` operation is done in `Unsafe` by some special native operation on the pointer.

Comment: Yeah, though this answer has been accepted it is actually incorrect. You can check the source if you like. As some have said here, it is an array of object references, *any one of which* can be updated atomically. Not with respect to any other reference in the array though. It saves space vs an AtomicReference[], by only using one set of the stuff needed to perform this magic (the Unsafe class) and using offsets to alter any one of the object references it holds. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.java

Answer (score 4):

It could be useful if you have a large number of objects that are updated concurrently, for example in a large multiplayer game.

An update of reference `i` would follow the pattern

```
boolean success = false;
while (!success)
{
    E previous = atomicReferenceArray.get(i);
    E next = ... // compute updated object
    success = atomicReferenceArray.compareAndSet(i, previous, next);
}
```

Depending on the circumstances this may be faster and/or easier to use than locking (`synchronized`).

Answer (score 2):

One possible use case would have been ConcurrentHashMap which extensively uses array internally. Array can be volatile but at per element level sematics can't be volatile. it's one of the reason automic array came into existence.

Answer (score 1):

some notes from a C++ programmer below, please don't condemn my Java much :)

`AtomicReferenceArray` allows to avoid false sharing, when multiple CPU logical cores access the same cache line that is changed by one of the thread. Invalidating and re-fetching the cache is very expensive. Unfortunately there is no `sizeof` in Java, so we don't know how many bytes each `AtomicReference` takes, but assuming it's at least 8 bytes (the size of a pointer on 64-bit architectures), you can allocate as follows:

```
// a lower bound is enough
private final int sizeofAtomicReference = 8;
// good for x86/x64
private final int sizeofCacheLine = 64;
// the number of CPU cores
private final int nLogicalCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); 
private final int refsPerCacheLine = (sizeofCacheLine + sizeofAtomicReference - 1) / sizeofAtomicReference;
private AtomicReferenceArray<Task> tasks = new AtomicReferenceArray<Task>(nLogicalCores *  refsPerCacheLine);
```

Now if you assign a task to `i`-th thread via

```
tasks.compareAndSet(i*refsPerCacheLine, null, new Task(/*problem definition here*/));
```

you guarantee that the task references are assigned to different CPU cache lines. Thus there is no expensive false sharing. So the latency of passing tasks from the producer thread to the consumer threads is minimal (for Java, but not for C++/Assembly).

**Bonus**:
You then poll the `tasks` array in the worker threads like this:

```
// consider iWorker is the 0-based index of the logical core this thread is assigned to
final int myIndex = iWorker*refsPerCacheLine;
while(true) {
    Task curTask = tasks.get(myIndex);
    if(curTask == null) continue;
    if(curTask.isTerminator()) {
        return; // exit the thread
    }
    // ... Process the task here ...
    // Signal the producer thread that the current worker is free
    tasks.set(myIndex, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceArray;

public class AtomicReferenceArrayExample {
    AtomicReferenceArray<String> arr = new AtomicReferenceArray<String>(10);

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Thread(new AtomicReferenceArrayExample().new AddThread()).start();
        new Thread(new AtomicReferenceArrayExample().new AddThread()).start();
    }

    class AddThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Sets value at the index 1
            arr.set(0, "A");
            // At index 0, if current reference is "A" then it changes as "B".
            arr.compareAndSet(0, "A", "B");
            // At index 0, if current value is "B", then it is sets as "C".
            arr.weakCompareAndSet(0, "B", "C");
            System.out.println(arr.get(0));
        }
    }

}

//    Result:
//        C
//        C
```